# Testing Facebook Messenger Bot Payments outside of the US

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Trying to test Bot payments outside of the US. I am following this documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/complete-guide/payments

Since I am not in US, I can only test, and I am not allowed to setup a payment provider (Paypal or Stripe). But when I try to test using the simple Buy button option (and obviously setting *"is_test_payment": True*, and testing with an admin user) I get following error message:

> 400 {"error":{"message":"(#1158) No valid payment
>   provider found. Please add a valid payment provider, it can be
>   tokenized payment, stripe or paypal.", "type":"OAuthException" ,"code":1158, "error_subcode":2018106, "fbtrace_id":"GbujhLzHh7U"}}

How do I solve this? Again, I only want to test for the time being.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the tokenized card option as a payment provider?

Comment: Not yet, I was hoping to test the simpler button payment option with the built in payment provider, as per above